# Пытаюсь запустить fastapi, но на моменте uvicorn main:app --reload выдает ошибку

Tags: python, fastapi

В консоли вводил такие команды:

```
pip install fastapi
pip install "fastapi[all]"
pip install "uvicorn[standard]"
```

потом создал файл main.py, содержимое файла в скрине, и после введения команды:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

выдает это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: `uvicorn` нет в рабочей папке и нет среди папок переменной окружения PATH, поэтому терминал не смог найти исполнительный файл. Скорее всего, `uvicorn` есть в папке питона, тогда нужно ту папку добавить в PATH

Answer (score 2):

В ошибке написано, что неизвестная команда uvicorn. Скорее всего у тебя не подтянулось окружение.
Рекомендую использовать [виртуальное окружение(venv)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) для проектов.

Без venv можно попробовать

```
python -m uvicorn main:app --reload
```